# Load specific strings into separate textBox fields from multi line file using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, textbox

I have file with multiple strings, what is opened used button and `openFileDialog`. Aim is to load each unique string to single textBox.

```
private void OpenClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
        {
```

Each of such file will always have the same codes(0.0.5; 0.1.2*26 etc.), only the values inside "()" will change.

Please show exact examples, how would be the best way to hardcode and get results like:

```
textBox1= 2008/12/22 08:10:02
textBox2= DC331TMMBA5BAC
textBox3= 00000000
textBox4= 45889662
textBox5= TA-6301
textBox6= 
textBox7= 0812210743
textBox8= 5000*1
textBox9= 0812210745
textBox9= 0000 textBox10= 0306021530
```

**part of data block in file:**

```
*** 2008/12/22 08:10:02 *** SLB
\@DC331TMMBA5BAC
F.F(00000000)
0.0.0(45889662)
0.0.1(TA-6301 )
0.0.5(        )
0.1.2*26(0812210743)
0.3.3(  5000*1/kWh)
C.64.0*01(0812210745)
1.6.1*26(0000*kW)(0306021530)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var rx = new Regex(
        @"\s*\*+(?<1>[0-9/\s:]+)\*+.*" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"\s*\\@(?<2>.+).*" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"[^\(]*\((?<3>.+)\).*" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"[^\(]*\((?<4>.+)\).*" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"[^\(]*\((?<5>.+)\).*" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"[^\(]*\((?<6>.+)\).*" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"[^\(]*\((?<7>.+)\).*" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"[^\(]*\((?<8>.+)\).*" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"[^\(]*\((?<9>[^\)]+)\)[^\(]*\((?<10>[^\)]+)\)");

    var str = @"*** 2008/12/22 08:10:02 *** SLB
                \@DC331TMMBA5BAC
                F.F(00000000)
                0.0.0(45889662)
                0.0.1(TA-6301 )
                0.0.5(        )
                0.1.2*26(0812210743)
                0.3.3(  5000*1/kWh)
                C.64.0*01(0812210745)
                1.6.1*26(0000*kW)(0306021530)";

    var m = rx.Match(str);

    var text1 = m.Groups["1"].Value;
    var text2 = m.Groups["2"].Value;

    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work okay..

```
var date = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})").Groups[0].Value;
var secondLine = Regex.Match(input, @"\\@(.*)").Groups[1].Value;
var theRest = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?:\()([^)]+)(?:\))");

Console.WriteLine(date); // 2008/12/22 08:10:02
Console.WriteLine(secondLine); // DC331TMMBA5BAC

foreach (Match match in theRest) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Full results:

```
2008/12/22 08:10:02
DC331TMMBA5BAC
00000000
45889662
TA-6301

0812210743
5000*1/kWh
0812210745
0000*kW
0306021530
```

Comment: Not exactly what i asked, as there is no input used, but:
    private void OpenClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))

Also your result didnt use any textBox :)

Comment: I gave you a way to cherry pick what you want. I didn't spoon feed you the whole solution.. its now your job to take what I have given you and plug it into your project .. same as everyone who asks a question here.